# Rdlc Report does not show changes from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc

I know that this question was asked before, but there is no relevant answer for it. The problem is that my rdlc Report shown in a reportViewer C# does not reflect the changes from the SQL Server database made at run-time (inserts, updates, deletes). It shows only the oldest data. If I close the program and run it again, it works but this is not the solution.

Comment: Are you caching the results in session? You're not clear on how the report is generated through the app.

Comment: Yes. I have a form which inserts items in a table, and another one with the report. If I insert an item with the first form the database is updated, but this changes are not shown in the second form(with the report) only if I close the app and run it again. I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: Sounds like you need a refresh to the dataset for the report.

Comment: Yes, probably this is the problem. I tried using this code this.TRANZACTIONSTableAdapter.FillByParam(this.DataSetTranzactiiGrafic.TRANZACTII, 7); this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();    but does not do anything. Only the old data is there.

Comment: what does the 7 represent in this case? Also, when the report view is attached there's usually some code autogenerated much like what you showed in your comment. What does it look like?

Comment: That was the autogenerated code, and  7 was a parameter for FillByParam.

Comment: I understand what the 7 was for, just why you were specifying it upon adding new data. Your answer below seems to show you're not interested in a parameter as you just select everything from TRANZACTIONS. Thought maybe you needed to do a fill and refresh without the param.

Comment: After the code written below have to appear the two lines of code with FillByParam() and refreshReport(). I think that this sql string could be any valid query. I mention that I found the solution on a forum for Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution . It seems that before the two lines of code written by me, had to be something like this:

```
 String sql = "select * from TRANZACTIONS";
    this.TRANZACTIONSTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
    this.TRANZACTIONSTableAdapter.Connection = new 
    SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString");
    this.TRANZACTIONSTableAdapter.Connection.CreateCommand().CommandText = sql;
```

and after that calling the fill method and refresh the reportViewer.
I am not sure if it is the correct way to solve the problem, but it works fine for me.